# "Put on" makeup and "apply" make up

Tags: meaning

What is difference between "put on" makeup and "apply" makeup? please explain with some sentences.

Answer (score 2):

They mean just the same. *Put on* is a more colloquial expression.

- She always puts on make-up before going to work.
- How to [apply](http://m.wikihow.com/Apply-Makeup) make-up.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put%20on%20make-up%2Capply%20make-up&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cput%20on%20make%20-%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capply%20make%20-%20up%3B%2Cc0) put on make-up  vs apply make-up.